# Place an Imageview under a Texview after passing intent

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I need to put an ImageView under a TextView that was constructed using java. The textview  is displaying information from a previous activity. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.a_simple_ui;
public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    Intent recieve = getIntent();
    String message = recieve.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);
    setContentView(textView);
}
}
```

So now I need a picture under the textview above and to change the background color. Either by java or XML. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not. I'm building the textView in java. This activity doesn't use XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any approach from bellow two suggestion:

1) If your layout design is fixed than it is better to use xml based layout (static layout) rather than adding layout run-time.

For that first create xml layout main_Activity.xml like:

**main_Activity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDesc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <Imageview
            android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity2 .java**

> package com.example.a_simple_ui; public class MainActivity2 extends
>   Activity {
>
> @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
> ```
> setContentView(textView);  Intent recieve = getIntent();
> String message = recieve.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
> TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDesc);
> textView.setTextSize(40);
> textView.setText(message); } }
> ```

2) You need to add TextView and Imageview in linearlayout then need to set that linearlayout in setContentView() like:

```
    package com.example.a_simple_ui;
    public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        Intent recieve = getIntent();
        String message = recieve.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        layout.addView(textview);
        layout.addView(imageView);

        setContentView(layout);
    }
    }
```

Comment: This looks like it should work, but in implementing it, it crashed my phone.

Comment: Never mind, I got it. The change 1) worked. thank you for your help

Comment: @Himanshu-HD, plus me too, as our answers are retty the same))) I pluse you! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, actually I can't understand, why you use `TextView` class as you content view. In that case, you can, offcourse, make you own textview extending default one and create particular layout with imageview for it, but, the easiest (and more logical) way is to create lauout file for your activity with `TextView` and `ImageView`.

For example, it can be something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView  
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

And your activity onCreate method will be looks something like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(textView);  
 Intent recieve = getIntent();
 String message = recieve.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
 TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
 textView.setTextSize(40);
 textView.setText(message);
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
```

}

You need to call setContentView **before** finding views by id.

If you have to create texview dynamic, from java (I can't see any reason for it from your code) you can add **id** property to `LinearLayout` and than find it by id and add texview to that, and it will be placed after imageview.

p.s. Actually there are a lot of ways to do that, please, define your question more preciselly if my answer doesn't suits you

p.p.s. If you really have to create textView in runtime and you can't use xml layouts, you can create `LinearLayout` in runtime (`LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this)` and after that, create textView and ImageView and add that two views to that layout, after that make set this layout as content view for the activity

Comment: How will the imageview be displayed? I will add some pictures to show how it is working with my current code and explain what i need.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand your question. What do you mean by "how imageview be displayed"? It will be displayed as a view)